When $2003$ is divided by a number, the remainder is $23$ how many of such numbers exist?

When $2003$ is divided by a number, the remainder is $23$ how many of such numbers exist?

We are looking for $n>23$ where $kn+23=2003$. Hence we have $kn=1980=2^2\times3^2\times5\times11$. So we are looking for number of devisors of $1980$ that are larger than $23$. I know that $1980$ has $36$ positive divisors, but should I use brute force and count how many of them are $\le23$ to exclude, or there is a more systematic approach to proceed?

All divosors are of the form $2^a\times 3^b\times 5^c\times 11^d$ where $0\le a\le 2; o\le b\le 2;0\le c\le 1; 0\le d\le 1$.  How many is that?

@fleablood Not sure what your comment is about. OP already said that 1980 has 36 positive divisors. They are asking about how to exclude those that are $ \leq 23$ apart from brute force.

@CalvinLin well, yeah.  I never said that was the final answer.... So count the ones that are $\le 23$ and subtract them

@fleablood The point I'm making is that your comment adds nothing to the post (and in fact could confuse others about what is going on).

Just count the ones that less than $23$.  Subtract the two multiples of $11$ that are $\le 22$.  The four multiples of $5$ that are $\le 25$.  Of the nine  $2^03^0$ to $2^23^2$ that contain at most factors of $2$ and $3$  only $4\times 9$ is too large so there are eight to subtract.  So $36 -2 -4-8= 22$.  $22$ such numbers.

I must say, I find that your equation does not mesh with your highlighted question, as stated. Namely, for me, if a number $N$, when divided by 2003, has remainder $23$, then it must be that $$ N = 2003 \cdot q + 23, $$ for some integer $q$. I am not saying that this is what you want, but I do think that your phrasing is confusing at best.

I wrote down the divisors less than 23, number of them is 11. If we also include 1 and 23 we get 13. I could not find using formula , it gave 8 if you include 1 and 23 it becomes 10. a bit confusing. I think the correct number is 13.

@sirous I followed fleablood's suggested way for counting comment and got $14$: multipliers of $11$ are: $11,22$. of $5$ are $5,10,15,20$, and divisors in the form $2^k3^m$ less than $23$ are $3\times3-1=8$, excluding $36$ (it also includes $1$).
